# Making 49 from 5, 1, 3, 4

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

I have these numbers: 5, 1, 3, 4. There are four different ways to make 49 - what are they?

Comment: What are the allowed operations?

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: Along with the above issues, do the numbers have to be in order? I'm okay with re-opening this as long as there is much clearer definition with regards to the question posed.

Answer (score 8):

Solutions are below:

1.

> $15+34$

2.

> $45+1+3$

3.

> $4^3-15$

4.

> $15*3+4$

5.

> $53-4/1$

6.

> $53^1-4$

7.

> $53/1-4$

Comment: Also, 43 + 5 + 1 (is it a spoiler if the question is on hold?)